# Is there any way to "disable" the use of code generated by the designer in Visual Studio IDE 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am working on a Windows Forms desktop application in the Visual Studio IDE 2022. Initially, I used the designer to create all the components and views. This was all done in the Main form. The project became a little more serious, so I decided that I should implement some sort of MVC architecture, which meant the components and views all get initialized and created in the separate View classes. The main panel everything sits on will still get created in the Main form, and then every View class puts its own controls on this main panel the same way the designer did. In this case, I have no use for the code generated by the designer. However, before I go deleting designer code (which is working fine), I still want to test the new architecture I have, which means I need to somehow disable the designer. Is there any way to disable the designer code from being used without deleting it?

Thank you for the help in advance, and let me know if any more details need to be included in the post!

Comment: Comment it out (literally, or via `#if false`) in the `FormName.designer.cs` file (or whatever language you're using), if I'm understanding you right...?